# SOLR Analysis Query

Tags: join, solr, analysis

I have a SOLR instance with millions of documents. The schema is well defined (i.e. all fields are typed). All the searching/faceting etc. works ok without any issues.

However, I am trying to do something new which I "think" is not supported in current version. I am running SOLR 3.5 on Windows using Jetty.

To simplify the question, my document contains some fields like:

Id,
Name,
City,
JobTitle

Lets say I have a sample data like:
P Wood, London, Director
J Smith, London, Project Manager
D Lock, Brighton, Developer
K Pracy, London, Developer

For the sake of example, assume that this is a matching system which allows people to find each other. Also assume that Id is unique Id.

I want to write a "sampling" query which should find me the set of records that will match other records for any criteria.

So for example, I want to define a criteria like:

Find me the people who will match people in different cities with differfent job titles:

If the above schema was a RDBMS-SQL table (lets say People), the approximate query would be something like this:

```
SELECT P.Id, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(1) 
        FROM People PI Where PI.Id != P.Id
        AND PI.City != P.City
        AND PI.JobTitle != P.JobTitle
    ) AS FindCount
FROM
People P
```

Well, the query may not be workable but you get the idea. Anyway, there are other requirements also that Findcount should be greater than x and less than y.

Can someone let me know if this is possible in SOLR or if this is something not meant for SOLR. I know SOLR 4 is coming with a Join operator but that seems to me more like an IN clause which limits the use. For example, consider that I want the matching Id's also in above query rather than counts.

Comment: A 5-6 year old question being down voted today? Maybe you should leave an explanation on why this is not good for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is doable in 1 query and you might end up with running "inner select" as separate query for every person